# Operator Precedence in PHP: Ternary XOR Assignment

Tags: php, operator-precedence

After writing my response on the question [how to assign to multiple variables in a ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259962/is-it-possible-to-set-multiple-variables-with-one-ternary-operator) I actually tried out the code I wrote:

```
true ? $w = 100 xor $r = 200 : $w = 300 xor $r = 400;
var_dump($w); var_dump($r);
```

(Don't bother it's useless, this is theoretic.)

Now, I would expect PHP to do it this way, according to [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```
 true  ?   $w = 100  xor  $r = 200   :   $w = 300  xor  $r = 400  ;
(true) ? ( $w = 100  xor  $r = 200 ) : ( $w = 300  xor  $r = 400 );
(true) ? (($w = 100) xor ($r = 200)) : (($w = 300) xor ($r = 400));
```

As the first part of the ternary operator is evaluated, this should output:

```
int 100
int 200
```

But instead I get

```
int 100
int 400
```

This is very odd to me, because it would require that parts of **both parts of the ternary operator** are executed.

Suppose it's some fault in my thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aren't you just doing

```
(true ? $w = 100 xor $r = 200 : $w = 300) xor $r = 400;
```

Comment: Just like the one-command for loop without braces that someone tags a second command onto, and finds out it's only done once at the end. Oops.

Comment: This makes sense, I think PHP is putting that last xor outside of the operator. Like with calculators, you **need to include parentheses around everything**.

Comment: followed your link to php.net and it's just there, `xor` precedence is lower than `?:` QED.

Comment: what I like best is macros in C with too little parentheses, like `#define AVERAGE(x,y) x/2+y/2` and then evaluating `AVERAGE(10,1)*2`. oh the joy. even better when using lowercase, so the macro hint isn't even there.

Comment: damn it, you're perfectly right. I'm always trapped by the ternary. @C: Yeah, I know that. But with C it's somehow practice to surround the macro and all variables with parentheses. In PHP I'm used to not using them. Backfires sometimes...

Comment: this reminds me of this *(c++) precedence question... even getting all parentheses right: `#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))`, predict output of `int c=2;printf("%d\n",SQUARE(++c));`

Comment: Translating the makro: `c=2;printf("%d\n",((++c)*(++c)));` And this is: `c=2;printf("%d\n",3*4);`. So it outputs `12`, does it?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use the ternary operator in this way at all.  Use the ternary operator when you need the whole expression to return a value, not as a substitute for logical code constructs.

For example:

```
if (true) {
  $w = 100;
  $r = 200;
} else {
  $w = 300;
  $r = 400;
}

var_dump($w); 
var_dump($r);
```

Advantages of using if/else construct:

- Easier to read, easier to maintain, easier to debug.
- Easier to add more steps inside each conditional block if the need arises.
- If you run tests using code coverage tools, you get a more accurate view of which code paths are being tested when all your code isn't on one line.
- You don't have to post a question to Stack Overflow to get it working!

Advantages of using ternary operator:

- Uses fewer curly-braces and semicolons, in case you're running out of them or can't find them on your keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, I would never even think of using this. The question was purely theoretical ;) But hay, you said it: On my German Keybord I have to Press `Alt Gr + 7` to open a curly brace... Quite complicated, isn't it?

Comment: Point taken.  In many national keyboard layouts, `Alt Gr` is required to get access to curly braces and other characters common in programming languages.